# WPF application using Geckofx-15 inside WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-thread, geckofx

I have wpf application which uses geckofx inside WindowsFormshost to display websites

sometimes GeckoWebBrowser becomes not reponsive

specially when loading heavy pages

I know how to run Window in seperate UI thread but
is it possible to run WindowsFormsHost in seperate UI thread ?